# Xamarin.Android app resumed by shortcut intent - Master and Detail must be set before adding MasterDetailPage to a container

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, prism

I have Xamarin.Android todo list mobile app using Prism.

The problem is:

- In android system, I can create shortcut to open specific list in
  app.
- When I open app, and press home button, it remains on background
  (thats ok)
- When I then run app from desktop shortcut, it opens
  android activity and when I create new PrismApplication (
  `LoadApplication(new App());` ) everything is running OK, but after
  creating viewmodel for view, app is still using old viewmodel from
  before.

I made this workaroud and I use same instance of PrismApplication:

```
static App xamApp;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    if (xamApp == null)
    {
        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        xamApp = new App();
    }

    LoadApplication(xamApp);
    xamApp.Redirect(Intent.GetStringExtra("ListID"));
}
```

Now, problem is redirecting. This code:

```
public void Redirect(string listId)
{
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"MainPage/MainNavigationPage/TodoList?id={listId}", animated: false);
}
```

leads to the error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Master and Detail must be set before adding MasterDetailPage to a container.`

Prism should take care of Binding of Detail in MasterDetailPage by the "TodoList" from NavigateAsync uri.

Does enyone know what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got it working.

- First I used LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask in my ActivityAttribute of MainActivity

  [Activity(Label = "..", **LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask**, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true]

  public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
- Then I used **OnNewIntent** method of **FormsAppCompatActivity** so after app is on backgroud, only this event is launched :

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    var listId = intent.GetStringExtra("ListID");
    ((App)App.Current).Redirect(listId);
}
```

- Now even `$"MainNavigationPage/TodoList?id={listId}"` works

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you provided, I am assuming that when the app is launched again, it is already running, your previous MasterDetail page is already on the stack.  IN your reset method, you want to reset your navigation stack to the new uri passing in the parameter.  IN this case, you should use an absolute uri.  This means try adding a "/" prefix to your uri.  So something like this:

```
public void Redirect(string listId)
{
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"/MainPage/MainNavigationPage/TodoList?id={listId}", animated: false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, app is already running on background (problem appeared only if app was already running). I tried this absolute URI and result was the same. Problem was I was using default LaunchMode so maybe new instance of app was created but somehow using old PrismApplication, even when I created new: `LoadApplication(new App());`. I am new to android development so I am not exactly sure how (or if) this could happend.